# IE 8 Issue not recognizing selector

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have no idea why IE 8 does not recognize this selector " *= "

This is the doctype I am using for the site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The selector works for all browsers except for IE 8 - any suggestions?

Here is the full selector:

```
.contourErrorMsg[style*="display: inline;"],
.contourErrorMsg[style*="display:inline;"] {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: `*=` is not the full selector. Did you mean `[att*=val]` for a certain att and val? You need to show us your actual HTML and CSS.

Comment: I believe that is CSS3 only, which IE8 does not support.

Comment: @Shmiddty: IE8 does support it. Just because it's CSS3 does not automatically mean IE8 doesn't support it.

Comment: @BoltClock The full selector has been added to the original post

Answer (score 1):

Without the markup or a JSfiddle demonstrating the problem, it's difficult to say for sure what's causing your problem.  [IE8 does support the substring attribute selector (` [*=]')](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It could be that there is *something else* in your document which is putting IE8 into quirks mode; in which case this selector is not supported by IE8.

Perhaps you're missing the semi-colon at the end of `display:none`. (See http://jsfiddle.net/vKCU3/.)  That selector matches on the actual characters in the attribute, not the rendered display style, so such small things make a difference.

Try removing characters from the selector until you see a match, I.E.:

```
.contourErrorMsg[style*="display"]
{ color: red; }
```

Also be sure that `.contourErrorMsg` is the correct class.